# Pandas get all rows based on date column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a df with a column costs and a column date
What i want is to get all the amounts based on a single day, in order to add them all together, so i know how much i spend on a certain day, 
the problem is that i have this

```
parsed_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(payout_date, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
helper_date=parsed_date
helper_date+= datetime.timedelta(days=1)

mask=(df["date"]>=parsed_date) & (df["date"]<helper_date)
same_payout=df.loc[mask]
print("Parsed "+str(parsed_date))
print("Helper "+str(helper_date))
print(same_payout)
```

and i get this

```
Parsed 2016-08-03 00:00:00
Helper 2016-08-04 00:00:00
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, costs, date]
Index: []
```

and i dont know what im doing wrong

here is a sample of the info in the dataframe
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuM0y.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Grouper` object:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D'))['Costs'].sum()
```

Comment: wouldnt that sum the whole 'Costs' column?

Comment: @Duke No, it would give one sum of `Costs` for *each unique value* of `date`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: not for each unique value, but for each day, i might have a costs registered at 11am, and another one at 11:30am, so those 2 whould be added since they are registered in the same day

Comment: i first got that its only available with datetimeindex, blablabla, i changed it now it says 'The grouper name date is not found'